# How can I make logistic regression(Gradient Decendent) Code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am freshman and beginner ,
i have a trouble with making logistic regression algorithm.
i attached code in my textbook. what code should i fill in the blank?
within 4~5 lines would be good.
Thank you so much

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = datasets.make_classification(
    n_samples=200, n_features=2, random_state=333,
    n_informative=2, n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1)

def sigmoid(s):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

def loss(y, h):
    return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()

def gradient(X, y, w):
    return -(y * X) / (1 + np.exp(-y * np.dot(X, w)))


X_bias = np.append(np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X, axis=1)
y = np.array([[1] if label == 0 else [0] for label in y])
w = np.array([[random.uniform(-1, 1)] for _ in range(X.shape[1]+1)])
max_iter = 100
learning_rate = 0.1
threshold = 0.5

for _ in range(max_iter):

# fill in the blanks


probabilities = sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias, w))
predictions = [[1] if p > threshold else [0] for p in probabilities]
print("loss: %.2f, accuracy: %.2f" %
(loss(y, probabilities), accuracy_score(y, predictions)))
```

## fill in the blanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically very simple.

Define the hypothesis Function:

```
theta0 = 0
theta1 = 0

def hyp(x): return theta0 + theta1*x
```

Define the Cost function:

```
def cost(hyp, x, y):
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0

    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        total1 += hyp(x[i]) - y[i]
        total2 += (hyp(x[i]) - y[i]) * x[i]

return total1 / len(x), total2 / len(x)
```

Call the Function:

```
for i in range(50):
    s1, s2 = cost(hyp, x, y)
    theta1 = theta1 - alpha * s2
    theta0 = theta0 - alpha * s1
```

Learning parameters will be updated.